# Where to put the dot at the end of a sentence when using cases-figure?

Tags: meta-math

Often I use the cases-figure at the end of a sentence and I never know where to put the dot at the end of the sentence.

I think, there are two options.

**Option 1**: I can put the dot in the last case:

I get a sentence that looks like
$$
\begin{cases}\text{case 1}, & \text{condition 1}\\\text{case 2}, & \text{condition 2}.\end{cases}
$$

**Option 2**: I can put the dot at the end of all cases:

I get a sentence that looks like
$$
\begin{cases}\text{case 1}, & \text{condition 1}\\\text{case 2}, & \text{condition 2}\end{cases}.
$$

Personally, I prefer the second option.

But what is the correct way?
What is your preference/ experience?

*Dont know what are the right tags for this question, sorry.*

Comment: The first is correct.

Comment: Agree with Ullrich, but I would add a comma after contition 1. Note that this is necessary if you write out the sentence without using cases-figure.